# function works when I run it in javascript file but not embedded in html file

Tags: javascript

I am just starting with this so please bear with me. Can you please check why function `listfiles` is not working. If I put it in a separate js file and run, logs show the needed output. But inside html, nothing is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
The global function (listfiles) returns the filenmes with certain pattern:
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function listfiles() {

var Extras = "19ibxiuX-xcyNXGs4GBNR_W8zLXSz3mhS";
var filetype = "text/csv";
var filenameformat = /^Report-\w{3}-[A|D]-\d{8}.csv$/;

var fileIterator = DriveApp.getFolderById(Extras).getFiles();

var file;
var filenames = [];
var count = 0;
//Logger.log(count);
filenames[0]="";
//Logger.log(filenames[count]);

while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = fileIterator.next();
    //Logger.log(file.getName().search(filenameformat));
    if (file.getName().search(filenameformat) == 0 && file.getMimeType() == filetype) {
    count = count + 1; 
    filenames[count] = file.getName();
    Logger.log(count);
    Logger.log(filenames[count]);
    Logger.log(file.getMimeType());
    }
   };
 return filenames;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = listfiles(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `put it in a seperate js file and run`? *How* are you running the code? And what's `DriveApp`? - Wait, is this Google Apps Script? You can't just run that like regular JavaScript.

Comment: might have not getting reference to  'DriveApp' object.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: DriveApp is not defined

Comment: Yes I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: DriveApp is not defined
I am running this in scripts.google.com. You can define gs files and html files. When I have the funtion in a gs file and I run it. I can see the filenames in the log. But when I embed the script in html file, I get DriveApp not defined :). Hope I am making myself clear

Answer (score 1):

You script doesn't work because it's not meant to be run like that.
What you have isn't written in Javascript, but in Google Apps Script.
Try running this on [script.google.com](http://script.google.com).

Comment: I am running it in scripts.google.com. I enabled the API also from the resources menu

Comment: what else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The Apps Script API is specific to Google Apps Script and cannot be used in plain JavaScript. The Apps Script API is a set of APIs that provide access to the functionality of Google Apps Script, which is a scripting language based on JavaScript that runs on Google's servers.

If you want to use the functionality provided by the Apps Script API in your JavaScript application, you will need to use the API through Google Apps Script, which requires you to write your code in the Apps Script editor and run it as a Google Apps Script project.

However, if you have a standalone JavaScript application and want to access Google Drive functionality, you can use the Google Drive API, which is a RESTful API that allows you to interact with Google Drive from any programming language that can make HTTP requests. You can find more information about the Google Drive API at https://developers.google.com/drive/api.

For Google Docs, you can use the Google Docs API, which is a RESTful API that allows you to create, modify, and read Google Docs programmatically. The Google Docs API provides a way to automate common tasks such as creating new documents, updating existing documents, and formatting text. You can find more information about the Google Docs API at https://developers.google.com/docs/api.

For Google Forms, you can use the Google Forms service in the Google Apps Script API. Google Apps Script provides a way to create and manipulate Google Forms programmatically. You can use the FormApp class in the Google Apps Script API to create, modify, and read Google Forms. You can find more information about the FormApp class at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms.

Note that in order to use these APIs, you will need to authenticate your application with Google and obtain appropriate credentials. You can find more information about authentication and authorization for Google APIs at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2.